# Android Nexus5X suddenly died

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, fastboot, nexus-5x

My LG Nexus5X has randomly died this morning(it had ~70% battery). I have tried to leave it on charging for 1 hour straight and then tried to turn it back on. It worked. But then it randomly died again while being fully charged. It hasn't turned on ever since.

After shutting down for the second time I have also managed to enter the `Fastboot` menu (clicking Power Button+Volume Down button), although I get the menu to show and I can scroll through the options, when I click `Recovery mode` or `Start`, I get a screen with just saying `'Google'` on it and then dies again. For Start my understanding is that it should turn on and as for the Recovery Mode this is not a normal behaviour as I should be seeing an Android Robot as described [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/4596836?hl=en-GB). I also tried the `Power Off` option, left it there for an hour charging and then tried to turn it back on, this time it went past the `'Google'` page to the `colorful spinning/loading circles page` but the animation stuck and it turned off again.

After the above failure, my goal was to enter the Recovery Mode through my PC(I use Windows10): I have attempted to set up the drivers for `adb` and `fastboot` like described in this [guide](http://www.teamandroid.com/2012/07/30/how-to-set-up-adb-fastboot-with-android-sdk/). The only time I get my Android to show up in the Device Manager so I could setup the drivers is when the phone itself is in the fastboot mode and it shows up as `Kedacom USB Device->Android Bootloader Interface`. Since I could not see my Android under `Other Devices` like the guide says I tried to setup `adb/fastboot` one at a time for the `Kedacom USB Device->Android Bootloader Interface` entry. In the command line when I type  `adb devices` my device is not showing up `fastboot devices` this shows up: `0167ca36eedbc1ef        fastboot`. Also, when I type `adb reboot recovery` I get `error: no devices/emulators found` .

I have ran out of options and everything I tried does not seem to work. What is the solution to bring my Nexus5X back to life?

Comment: So it's recognized in fastboot. What's stopping you from just flashing a factory image? Locked bootloader?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How do I flash a factory image?

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/android/images). I'll have it posted as an answer if it works out for ya.

Comment: I followed the steps and when I execute the flash-all script it says "writing 'bootloader'...
FAILED (remote: device is locked. Cannot flash images)" . Is it maybe because I didnt enable "On-device Developer Options" when Nexus was alive?

Comment: Well yes... And do you have a custom recovery now? If not then you're pretty much out of luck - time to call Google.

Answer (score 2):

You should try flashing the factory image for Nexus 5X in Fastboot.

- Download Nexus 5X (bullhead) Factory image Android 7.1.1 [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/bullhead-nmf26f-factory-7ad6b52c.zip) or Android 6.0.1 [here](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/bullhead-mmb29v-factory-09b6d3d2.zip). And unzip the file.
- Setup all necessary drivers
- For commands to succeed, you should unlock the bootloader: 
  `fastboot oem unlock` or `fastboot flashing unlock`. The  device will show  a confirmation screen. (This erases all data on the device.)
- Open a terminal and navigate to where you unzipped system image previously downloaded.
- Execute the `flash-all script`. This script installs the necessary bootloader, baseband firmware, and  system.

Hope this helps you out.

If the above don't work, you should try instructions detailed on this [thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-5x/help/req-help-to-unbrick-t3251740).

Comment: OP did state he has a locked bootloader, so factory images are no go. The last link is very interesting though, I didn't know LG actually kept TOT capability intact for emergency.

Comment: I provide this solution for others too. I think the second solution should work for him.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when I follow the guide(for the last link you provided) and reach the step to connect the device for Windows to install the drivers it says "USB device not recognised"

Comment: You need drivers. Install them